# Implement a Favourites feature using SQLITE

Tags: android

I want to implement a favourites feature in my app where by a user can store items in a favourites table.

I have a table called recipes with 5 fields - id,name,summary,ingredients and directions
I have another table called faves with 2 fields - id and favs_id.

I am upto hear so far. How do I go about implementing favourites moving forward. Any tutorial link would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking  for is a simple `GROUP BY` query can achieve.

In here favorites will display first and then the rest .

Hope this helps

Go with something like this..

```
SELECT *
FROM recipes
INNER JOIN faves
ON recipes.fields_id=faves.fields_id
GROUP BY faves.fields_id
```

Haven't tested it but I am sure you get an idea.